# Bash completion on prompt is broken with current PS1

Tags: bash, prompt

I think something is wrong with the way I'm escaping sequences in my `PS1`. Actually, I know that's the issue. My question is what am I not escaping correctly?

```
declare __host='\[\e[30;102m\] \h \[\e[0m\]';
declare __dir='\[\e[1;97;44m\] \w \[\e[22m\]';
declare __arrow='\[\e[1m\]▸ \[\e[0m\]';

function __git_status() {
  local info;
  info=$(__git_info);

  [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && printf "\e[30;43m%s" "$info";
}

export PS1="$__host$__dir"'$(__git_status)'"$__arrow ";
```

The trick is coloring the arrow depending on whether or not `__dir` or `__git_status` precede it. Like so:[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, by the way, you shouldn't `export` a dynamically-generated PS1; child process shells won't have access to the metadata controlling it. And see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` keyword.

Comment: Hey, could you post how you get `__git_info` somewhere? I'm curious and would like to add it to my `bashrc` if that's okay.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Here ya go! https://gist.github.com/Nxt3/1a90673fbbe88d6ec01d8073b4d850d4

Answer (score 1):

The escape code in the `printf` lacks the `\[`...`\]` wrapper.

Tangentially, I would also factor out the useless explicit comparison to `$?` and the `function` keyword.

```
__git_status() {
  local info
  info=$(__git_info) &&
    printf '\\[\e[30;43m\\]%s' "$info"
}
```

Notice also the switch to single quotes around the format string and the doubled backslashes (see comments for details; thanks to Charles Duffy for guidance).

Shell script requires *either* semicolons or newlines between statements, you don't need both.

Comment: I had tried that. It then ends up looking like this in my PS1: https://imgur.com/ZLeVcjG.png

Comment: The link appears to be broken. But I'm guessing `printf` also eats one layer of backslahes; updated answer.

Comment: Indeed it does, but you want to be sure the backslashes make it doubled-up all the way to `printf` (ideally without relying on fallback behavior where a potential escape sequence simply wasn't recognized on account of the following character not being the second half of a well-defined sequence). Using double quotes muddies the waters -- a reader needs to think about both expansion stages and how they interact, whereas in single quotes a backslash is always *definitely* literal.

Comment: Indeed, thanks; updated to single quotes.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work either: https://imgur.com/XuebaCX.png

Comment: That's just **too many** doubled-up backslashes. Un-double the ones that are supposed to be escape sequence components (certainly, `\e`) while keeping the single quotes, and there you are.

Comment: `info=$(__git_info) && printf '\[\e[30;43m\]%s' "$info";` still has slashes present in the output.

Comment: Still no luck with your imgur links by the way. Uploading to Stack images might be better anyway; you can edit the question for update, upload the picture, copy the URL, and cancel the edit.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry about that. Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfiI3.png That's with your latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your gist. It looks like the answer to your question is that `printf` doesn't want to know about the `\[ \]` escapes on non-printing characters.

```
__git_status() {
  local info
  info=$(__git_info) &&
    printf '\e[30;43m%s' "$info"
}
```

works perfectly for me with your PS1 as set up, and will not have problems with determining prompt length. My only problem is that CentOS doesn't know how to print `⑂` in the terminal =(

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired outcome though. I wanted to keep the color from the previous block to be used on the arrow part. What you've done is escaped the sequence at the end, so now the arrow doesn't know about the previous color.

Comment: ...why not just set the arrow color to be the same as the dir color using `\[\e[1;97;44m\]` instead of what you currently have?

Comment: `__dir` has a blue background. `__git_status` has a yellow background. If in a git repo, then the arrow should have a yellow background to match `__git_status` (like the screenshot in the OP). However, if I'm not in a git repo, then the arrow's background should use the blue from `__dir`;

Comment: oh... if you just take out the `\e[m` (I edited my answer) it works like that for me.

Comment: Okay, so, use that, and then open up your bash prompt and go up in history to view previous commands. Do things get weird for you? Like, commands in the history not display properly like this? This happens when in a git repo.

Comment: Like this: https://gfycat.com/MenacingLikableCranefly

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't testing on multi-line commands, MB. That's super weird. I spent a while on this and couldn't figure it out. You could probably figure out a way to check if there's git info, if there is, append an arrow, if there's not, append the arrow to dir, and then put the color escapes in your PS1 instead of your printf. The code would look garbage, but at least it'd (probably) work...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change:

`info=$(__git_info) && printf '\e[30;43m%s' "$info"`

to

`info=$(__git_info) && printf '\1\e[30;43m\2%s' "$info"`

This is because bash internally replaces the prompting special characters [ and ] with ASCII 1 and 2 before my __git_status function is executed.